# Echo a if statement in the middle of a echo

Tags: php, html, if-statement, checkbox

I have a code with checkbox like:

```
Echo "<p>Some text go here (I NEED TO PUT HERE CHECKBOX CHECKED FROM IF), here goes another text.</p>"

if( isset( $_POST['check'] ))
{
    if( count( $_POST['check'] ) > 0 )
    {
        echo "" . implode(", ", $_POST['check']);
    }
```

I need to put the if from checkbox array in the middle of my echo, theres a way?

Tks

Comment: `echo "some stuff"; if( x) { echo "conditional stuff"; } echo "rest of stuff";` not working for some reason?

Comment: or `$checkboxes = ''; if (...){$checkboxes = implode(...) } echo "All stuff with ($checkboxes) inbetween";` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign the value to a variable, you can concetanate (ugh! this word...) it to one echo command.

```
if( isset( $_POST['check'] ))
{
    if( count( $_POST['check'] ) > 0 )
    {
        $var = implode(", ", $_POST['check']);
    } else {
        $var = "";
    }

echo "<p>Some text go here" . $var . ", here goes another text.</p>";
```

**Edit**

Added [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker)'s comment, as a more efficient way of the above echo command:

```
echo "<p>Some text go here", $var, ", here goes another text.</p>";
```

Comment: Or even just echo several elements: `echo "<p>Some text go here", $var, ", here goes another text.</p>";`.... the difference being that this statement doesn't entail any concatenation

Comment: @MarkBaker never used it this way, thanks for the comment! :)

Comment: Saves a little bit of memory and processor overhead needed for the concatenation

Comment: @MarkBaker So, I don't know, i put this on my code and are my code are not working more. Can you help me?